# Regex works only on first occurance?

Tags: c++, regex

**Update: Kindly read my comment on jignatius's answer**

---

I wrote the following code to find specific matches in a string using regex and to delete them and replace with another value, but it doesn't work as expected.
For example given the following input:

```
f={a,b}+{c,d}
```

I would expect it to delete both `{a,b}` and `{c,d}` but it only works on the first one, what is wrong with my code?

After Some checking I can see that the first loop is entered only once, but why?

Comment: Any help please?

Comment: I can't move on working on my project without solving this bug

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a standard library function, [`std::regex_replace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace), in the header `<regex>` that does what to want to do: text replacement based on a regex. That will simplify things quite a lot for you instead of using a hand crafted loop.

You just need to supply the input string, the regex to match against, and the replacement string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::regex reg(R"(\{[^}]*\})");
    std::string mystring = "f={a,b}+{c,d}";
    auto newstring = std::regex_replace(mystring, reg, "title");
    std::cout << newstring;  //f=title+title
}
```

Note: it's also easier to use a raw string literal with the format `R"(literal)"` to avoid using double backslashes to escape special characters in the regex.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qbdce7)

---

In your comment you say that the replacement text can change. In that case, you will have to do a loop, not a straight forward regex replace.

You can use [`std::regex_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator), a read-only forward iterator that will call `std::regex_search()` for you. You can use a string stream to build the new string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::regex reg(R"(\{[^}]*\})");
    std::string mystring = "f={a,b}+{c,d} + c";
        
    std::vector<std::string> replacements = { "rep1", "rep2", "rep3" };
    int i = 0;
    auto start = std::sregex_iterator(mystring.begin(), mystring.end(), reg);
    auto end = std::sregex_iterator{};
    std::ostringstream ss;

    for (std::sregex_iterator it = start; it != end; ++it)
    {
         std::smatch mat = *it;
         ss << mat.prefix() << replacements[i++];

         //If last match, stream suffix
         if (std::next(it) == end)
         {
             ss << mat.suffix();
         }
    }
    std::cout << ss.str();  //f=rep1+rep2 + c
}
```

Note that the `prefix()` method of the `std::smatch` object will give you the substring from the target string to the beginning of the match. Then you place your replacement text into the stream. Finally, you should use the `suffix()` method of the `std::smatch` object to stream any trailing text between the last match and the end of your target string.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/czPEMT)

Comment: **Please Note:** I am not going to replace all matches with a const string but something the changes from a mach to another. Plus I want to make some validation on the match before doing a replacement

Comment: @dure Look at my edit above. Is this what you're looking for? ps: I think you should put back your code in the question for future visitors.

Comment: I will write another example since I disclosed private code